# strict mode in chrome console not working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, strict

I'm trying to use strict mode in chrome console according to what I read these two method should work but only Method 1 is working. Is in Method 2 I'm doing something wrong or it is not possible to use strict mode like this.

Method 1:

```
(function f(){
    'use strict';
    function fn(text){herd=text; console.log(herd);}
    fn("Hi Welcome");
    })();
```

output of Method1

```
VM1139:3 Uncaught ReferenceError: herd is not defined
    at fn (<anonymous>:3:23)
    at f (<anonymous>:4:1)
    at <anonymous>:5:3
```

Method 2:

```
'use strict';
 function fnete(text) {as=text; console.log(as);}


'use strict'; fnete("hi");
```

output of method 2

```
hi
```

Attaching Image of error.
[image]

Comment: In chrome 57 it is not working

Comment: For me chrome 57 throws a `VM1721:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: as is not defined` error. But why to you want to ensure strict mode in the console at all?

Comment: I'm learning about strict mode.

Comment: Then you should use a regular js file and not the console. In some situations it has some unexpected behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem in Method 2 is that your variable name is `as` which is a keyword.

Try using the same variable name `herd` in Method 2 which might fetch the same result as Method 1.

Comment: Then the browser would complain about that. But the OP is asking why **no** error is thrown in a case where the OP would expect that an error is thrown.

Comment: @Naveen if it didn't show an error before when you used `as`, but now shows an error if you change it to `herd` then the resone is somewhere else. Maybe the page where you run your command in did define `as` already.

Comment: yes @t.niese you are right. When I did that on new page it worked fine.